# Why does a MySql query, valid in Workbench, return syntax errors in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, version

so i have 2 tables as table1 and table2 in 2 different databases as id_information and id_information_backup. Both the tables have the following columns: (id bigint, name varchar, surname varchar) I made this trigger where when the user enters name and surname in table1 , it calculates the ascii code of it and do some calculations and store it in the "name" column of the second table which is "table2". All of these has been done in Mysql workbench. when i import the code into phpmyadmin then it gives me too many syntax errors. I tried to figure what syntax errors do i have but i could not find. I am sharing the trigger below. Kindly help me if you can. I will really appreciate it. I guess it is because of the version that i used is MySQL workbench 8.0 and the version that i am importing this into is PHPmyadmin 4.9.4 . Fix the problem if you can please.

```
delimiter $$ 
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `id_information`.`table1_after_INSERT1` AFTER INSERT ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
declare p , r , copy, result, result1 decimal(64,0);
declare name1, surnam varchar(15);
declare a int;
set name1 = new.name;
set surnam = new.surname;
set a= 100;
set result =0;
set copy = 0;
set result1 =0;
set p =0 ;
set r =0 ;
with recursive cte as (
    select name1 as name1, left(name1, 1) as val, 1 as idx
    union all
    select name1, substring(name1, idx + 1, 1), idx + 1 
    from cte 
    where idx < char_length(name1)
)
select group_concat(ascii(val) + a order by idx separator '') ascii_word from cte into result;
with recursive ctee as (
    select surnam as surnam, left(surnam, 1) as vall , 1 as idxx
    union all
    select surnam, substring(surnam, idxx+ 1, 1), idxx+ 1 
    from ctee
    where idxx< char_length(surnam)
)
select group_concat(ascii(vall )  + a order by idxx separator '') ascii_word from ctee into result1;
select group_concat(result, result1) into copy;
insert into id_information_backup.table2  set table2.name = copy;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: *it calculates the ascii code of it and do some calculations and store it in the "name" column of the second table which is "table2".* Why decimal ASCII? Why not hexadecimal? PS. [minimal fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v2p8Y8ELDcrbhvQaMyvFA6/0)

Comment: *when i import the code into phpmyadmin then it gives me too many syntax errors.* What is your MySQL version? it must be 8+, not 5+.

Comment: Exactly it is 8.0. Now i am importing it in an online server and it has phpmyadmin 4.9.4. Can you please tell me how can i fix this.

Comment: First i chose bigint datatype where i am storing the value but i realized sometimes if the name and surname is big then bigint wont b able to store such big numbers. I am storing it as decimal (64,0) .

Comment: phpmyadmin which gives "too many syntax errors" tries to check query syntax before sending the query to MySQL. If its version is too old and it doesn't know 8+ version syntax it's not surprise that it will report about "errors". Check versions compatibility (current phpmyadmin and MySQL 8+).

Comment: How am i supposed to check this? can you provice a source please? I have been trying to fix this for so long now. It is not helping.

Comment: I don't know - I don't use phpmyadmin.

Comment: What about sharing even some of these errors?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run the command (by pressing the "Go" button at the bottom of the SQL text area), what happens?

If phpMyAdmin is showing the errors as red circles with a white `x` to the left of the SQL area before submitting, then these are syntax warnings that won't affect your ability to submit the query. These are provided as hints by the SQL linter in phpMyAdmin.

phpMyAdmin syntax warning:
[image: phpMyAdmin syntax warning]

If the errors come after submitting the statements, then the errors come from MySQL itself and aren't directly caused by phpMyAdmin.

MySQL syntax error:
[image: MySQL syntax error]

Answer (score 0):

In PHPMyAdmin you need to set up delimiter in a small box under the main query

It should be signed as "Delimiter" ;-)

I ended getting caught by that one a few time :-D